# ADODB OutOFMemory Error

Tags: visual-c++

In a C++ application am getting `E_OUTOFMEMORY` Error in the below line in windows 2012 server.

Code below

```
STDMETHODIMP 
CADORequest::GetServerDescription(
    wchar_t wcProvider[],
    size_t dwProvider,
    CServer& ServerData
                            )
{
    HRESULT hrSQL = E_FAIL;   

    ::CoInitialize(0);

    IADORecordBinding *picRs = NULL;
      _RecordsetPtr pRs("ADODB.Recordset");
      _CommandPtr pCmd("ADODB.Command");
```

and am getting in the below line

```
_RecordsetPtr pRs("ADODB.Recordset");
```

The same application is working in 2003 Server. But when i migrated to 2012 server.Am getting this server.

When i analyzed the 2003 server was having adodb 2.8 and 2012 server having Adodb 6.0

Any idea on how to fix this will be helpfull. Thanks

Comment: You could use less memory. :-) Seriously, you've provided nothing near enough information for anyone to offer an answer. A single line of code, entirely out of context, with no other details is pretty much meaningless. Please edit your question to provide more, or it will almost certainly be closed as "not a real question".

Comment: Added the function code...does this help ?